# Why is firebase Storage is overwriting the storage that should keep all user images each time a photo is uploaded?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am pretty sure the error lies in the set line. I thought .key should have made the writing dynamic, but instead the child photopost gets overwritten each time. What do I need to change in order for every upload to be stored vs overwritten.

```
class post{
    var imageDownloadURL: String?

    var image: UIImage!

    var caption: String!


    init(image: UIImage, caption: String) {
        self.image = image
        self.caption = caption
    }
    func save() {

        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let newPostRef = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid).child("PhotoPosts")
        let newPostRef1 = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid).child("PhotoPosts1")


        let newPostKey = newPostRef.key


        if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6){

            let imageStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images")


            let newImageRef = imageStorageRef.child(newPostKey)
            let newImageRef1 = imageStorageRef.child(newPostKey)


            newImageRef.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: {(snapshot) in
                self.imageDownloadURL =
                    snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                newPostRef.setValue(self.imageDownloadURL as Any)


            })



            newImageRef1.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: {(snapshot) in
                self.imageDownloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

                let keyToPost = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid).childByAutoId().key
                let f1: [String: Any] = [(keyToPost) : self.imageDownloadURL as Any]

                newPostRef1.updateChildValues(f1)


                               })


        }

    }


}
```

Here is the database rules:

```
    rules_version = '2';
  service firebase.storage {
   match /b/{bucket}/o {
     match /{allPaths=**} {
       allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
     }
  }
 }
```

Note: I know newimageref1 is referring to the same thing as newimageref, but I don't see how that could be logically causing the overwrite. I am pretty sure that is not what is causing the overwrite.

Update after correct answer:

Fetching the image.

```
 public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

    let immy = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView



        let person: Userx = people[indexPath.row]


        cell.postID = self.people[indexPath.row].postID


        if let PhotoPosts = person.PhotoPosts {
            let url = URL(string: PhotoPosts)
            immy.sd_setImage(with: url)

        }


        return cell

........

for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                    if people.key != thisUsersUid {
                        print("peoplekey",people.key)
                       let peoplePhotoPosts = peopleObject?["PhotoPosts"]  as? String
                            let peopl = Userx(PhotoPosts: peoplePhotoPosts, imageDownloadURL: peopleimageDownloadURL, postID: peoplepostID, ...)
                    self.people.append(peopl)





                    self.people.append(peopl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have one `newPostKey`, it can only have one value at a time. So in these two lines, you end up referencing the same location in Cloud Storage:

```
let newImageRef = imageStorageRef.child(newPostKey)
let newImageRef1 = imageStorageRef.child(newPostKey)
```

And since `newImageRef` and `newImageRef1` point to the same location, the last write overwrites whatever is at that location already.

I think you want to write to two distinct locations based on the lowest-level database key, in which case you'll need to make sure you set up the storage references based on the individual keys.

For example:

```
let newImageRef = imageStorageRef.child(newPostRef.key)
let newImageRef1 = imageStorageRef.child(newPostRef1.key)
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense so that there are 2 different entries in storage but wouldn't each one still be overwritten when a new user posts becuase newPostRef.key = newPostKey?

Comment: Yes. If you want each post to be unique, generate a new unique location with `childByAutoId`. So: `let newPostRef = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid).child("PhotoPosts").childByAutoId()`

Comment: Aah thanks. My issue now is that when fetching the images for, display the snapshot is out of whack with the autoID as part of the path. I added the part where I display and fetch the images to the question. Do you know how to alter that?

Comment: Sorry, this is becoming increasingly hard to help with. I highly recommend [creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we're dealing with a minimal, well-defined target. While the problem probably remained the same for you, it's now shifted twice for me, which makes it hard to help efficiently.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I will have a look and try to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Just a question: right now the images of all users are going to storage (which is correct, before there was only 1 for all users). However, in database, when a user posts the 2nd pic it goes underneath the first. It should replace the first in database and in storage there should be one pic for each user that uploads.